# How does one create a MarkupExtension with non-string parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I am working on a Custom MarkupExtension within a WPF application.  Every documented example I have seen uses string parameters from XAML to construct the new object.  Is it possible to use a non-string parameter?

In other words, how can I do something like this?

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Uri))]
public class RefPackUriExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    object _assembly = null;

    public RefPackUriExtension() { }

    public RefPackUriExtension(object assembly)
    {
        this._assembly = assembly;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //return an object by using the "_assembly" member somehow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters to your `MarkupExtension` are subject to the same parsing behavior as properties on CLR objects. You can use a `TypeConverter` to allow the user to provide a `string` that is converted to the target type, or you can use another `MarkupExtension`.

As an example of the former, see the `ColorConverter` class. As an example of the latter, see the `RelativeSource` class (which is used within the `Binding` `MarkupExtension`).

Comment: Are you sure this works?  Before I posted the question I tried using the Binding MarkupExtension and received a compile-time error.

Comment: What would be helpful is an example of the XAML used in such cases